# Why does my CSV export from FileMaker always have dates as DD/MM/YYYY regardless of the file and system settings?

Tags: database, relational-database, filemaker

I've done a series of tests and am unable to understand what determines the date format when exporting to a CSV from FileMaker 11.

In my tests, I always get date formats exported as DD/MM/YYYY (Swiss format). Why does it not depend on the system settings, or if the export format does depend on the systems settings, at what time are the settings read (upon creation of the DB, upon creation of the first record)

**Settings for all tests (as shown in images):**

- all auto-enter options off
- validation on, no override possible
- 4 digit year enforced

**Test "USA":**

- Mac region settings set to USA
- reboot
- starting with a database structure with no records, enter several new records and fill in the date column
- export as CSV, with the use layout formatting set to off

**Test "Switzerland":**

- Mac region settings set to Switzerland
- reboot
- starting with a database structure with no records, enter several new records and fill in the date column
- export as CSV, with the use layout formatting set to off

**Field options 1:**
[image: Auto-enter]
**Field options 2:**
[image: Validation]
**File options:**
[image: Text]

P.S. Here is a forum post from someone who seems to have the opposite problem of mine, namely that his settings are always in a USA format.
https://community.filemaker.com/thread/74566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export, you get the actual data stored in the field. If you want to get *formatted* data, you must turn ON the option "*Apply current layout's data formatting to exported data*" **and** you must have the field formatted **exactly** the way you want it on the current layout.

I don't know of a way to format a date field dynamically according to the current system's setting - so I don't think you can get the export to automatically adjust to that.

I believe you could export as XML and reformat the dates on-the-fly using a custom XSLT stylesheet, though. But I don't think that switching your OS settings is a good way to select the desired format.

Comment: Thanks again! I think this makes my new question "Why is data entered into the date field always DD/MMYYYY regardless of the region settings and regardless of it being displayed and validated as MM/DD/YYYY?" And a follow-up: How do I see the actual field contents? Apparently even with no special display settings it does adapt the display to the macs regional settings.

Comment: I believe data is stored in the file's saved settings, regardless of the format in use.

Comment: Where can I view and change the "file's saved settings"? Is there a place to change the regional settings at the file level?

Comment: The file's settings are inherited from the OS on which the file is first opened. You cannot change them - but you can save a copy of the file as clone and open the cloned file on the OS with the desired locale settings.